# How to configure a crontab to rsync via ssh on AWS using a pem file

Tags: ssh, cron, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS EC2 server. One is production and the other is a replica.
This command works from the command line.

```
  rsync -razv -e "ssh -i /home/ubuntu/migration/healthy.pem" /home/ubuntu/migration/hb610b.sql.gz  ubuntu@ec2-5-5-8-9.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/replica
```

but when I put it in a cronjob. I get this error.

```
 Host key verification failed. 
 rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
 rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Why am I getting the verification failed when trying to run the command in cronjob?

I have created the cronjob both by command line using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and by using webmin.

The results were the same either way.

Comment: Edit your question and add how you created the cron job. Did you use `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e` or some other way?

Comment: ... yeah the difference is possibly that your command line user has previously connected to the remote host and interactively added it to their known_hosts file

Comment: I am using webmin to create the cronjob

Comment: I have been running that command in a script file and it works fine there also. It seems logical that if the command runs in a shell script and from the command line it should run as a cronjob.

Comment: Why are you adding it to root's crontab if it depends on your user's credentials? Does it work as expected if you use `crontab -e` instead of `sudo crontab -e`?

Comment: The simple answer is I don't know the difference. I have tried it both ways from webmin to create the job using root and using ubuntu as the user and they both fail. I have not tried using root to create the crontab entry.

Comment: You were right. When I changed the user to ubuntu. The command worked. The file is being transfered via the cronjob. I did not realize that when I was running the command from the command line. I was not typing sudo. That was my clue to change the user in webmin.